# Proper way of non-blocking load of unrelated models for nested route in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My routes look roughly like this:

```

```
/
  /sites
    /:site_id
      /settings
        /user-defined-params
          /:param_id
```

```

Now in `/user-defined-params` I want to display table-list of parameters assigned to that given `site`. The models are not related, I mean `site` doesn't have collection of `params` as a relation, so I can't simply fetch them via this relation.

Should `model()` hook for my router return list of these params? By default the model seems to be `site` loaded from parent route (`:site_id`). What if loading takes some time and I'd like to actually display this table (so do actual transition) but then show kind of loading indicator waiting for table to fill in with the data.

When I try to load this in `model()` hook, transition blocks. When I try to load it in `afterModel()` hook, I don't have a way to assign it and make it available for template (other than force-assigning `params` property to `site` model, which seems to be wrong).

All the examples I've found over the Internet seem to be lacking this scenario, which I feel is one of the basic ones, so any hints on that? How should I load it (ideally without blocking transition)?

Comment: Maybe check out ember-parachute

Answer (score 0):

The defaults in Ember's current router (as you have found) are to block UI loading completely until the promised returned in model hooks have resolved. However, there's interest in adjusting that so we can easily build non-blocking UI patterns with the built-in router.

Right now, the community consensus here is to use `ember-concurrency` and it's derived state (specifically the `.isRunning` aspect of tasks) to toggle between a loading state and a screen with the data rendered. It isn't a coincidence that `ember-concurrency` was built by the guy behind the first router and the current router re-think that is in-process.

One example of an approach to this is outlined here:
https://emberway.io/skeleton-screen-loading-in-ember-js-2f7ac2384d63

I personally prefer to use my route to do the initial task loading and the consume the data in the template. But in a more complex UI I also will go with container components as outlined in that article.